# PHP Script to Ignore Placeholder Text in Input Fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, foreach

I have the following script called **form.php**: http://pastebin.com/kHiZ3gLY (I have pasted full script below)

When I complete the first set of 4 fields (leaving the other 2 sets with their placeholder text) and submit, my **var_dump** output is:

```
string '1|1|1|1

Height (cm)|Width (cm)|Length (cm)|Weight (kg)

Height (cm)|Width (cm)|Length (cm)|

' (length=133)
```

Is it possible that I can use PHP/jQuery to "ignore" the fields that have the placeholder text in place? So my output would just be:

```
string '1|1|1|1' (length=7)
```

Many thanks for any helpers here.

**full script:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>March 2012 Experiment</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://digitalbush.com/files/jquery/watermarkinput/beta1/jquery.watermarkinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("#p1height").Watermark("Height (cm)");
   $("#p1width").Watermark("Width (cm)");
   $("#p1length").Watermark("Length (cm)");
   $("#p1weight").Watermark("Weight (kg)");
   $("#p2height").Watermark("Height (cm)");
   $("#p2width").Watermark("Width (cm)");
   $("#p2length").Watermark("Length (cm)");
   $("#p2weight").Watermark("Weight (kg)");
   $("#p3height").Watermark("Height (cm)");
   $("#p3width").Watermark("Width (cm)");
   $("#p3length").Watermark("Length (cm)");
   $("#p3weight").Watermark("Weight (kg)");
});
</script>


</head>

<body>

<?php

$errors = '';

if (isset($_POST['submitform'])) {

    $ierrors = array();
    $all = '';

    // Loop over the values 1 through 3
    foreach( range( 1, 3) as $i)
    {
        // Create an array that stores all of the values for the current number
        $values = array( 
            'p' . $i . 'height' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'height'], 
            'p' . $i . 'width' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'width'], 
            'p' . $i . 'length' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'length'], 
            'p' . $i . 'weight' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'weight']
        );

        // Validate every value
        foreach( $values as $key => $value)
        {
            if( empty( $value))
            {
                $ierrors[] = "Value $key is not set";
            }
            // You can add more validation in here, such as:
            if( !is_numeric( $value))
            {
                $ierrors[] = "Value $key contains an invalid value '$value'";
            }
        }

        // Join all of the values together to produce the desired output
        $all .= implode( '|', $values) . "\n\n";
    }   

    var_dump($all);

}

?>

<form action="form.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="p1weight" name="p1weight" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 
    <input type="text" id="p1length" name="p1length" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 
    <input type="text" id="p1width" name="p1width" value=""  onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 
    <input type="text" id="p1height" name="p1height" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <input type="text" id="p2weight" name="p2weight" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 
    <input type="text" id="p2length" name="p2length" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 
    <input type="text" id="p2width" name="p2width" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 
    <input type="text" id="p2height" name="p2height" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <input type="text" id="p3weight" name="p3weight" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 
    <input type="text" value="" id="p3length" name="p3length" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 
    <input type="text" value="" id="p3width" name="p3width" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /> 
    <input type="text" id="p3height" name="p3height" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <input type="submit" name="submitform" id="submitform" />

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is one of the many reasons you shouldn't populate the value attribute of form fields with placeholder text. If you want to have placeholder text I recommend either looking onto [some javascript to overlay label](https://github.com/lrc/jquery-placeholder-text/blob/master/placeholder.js) elements or looking into the [HTML5 placeholder attribute](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder).

To actually answer your question though, you could use the javascript on submit event to filter the form fields before submission occurs. Something like this should get you started.

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('input[type=text]', this).each(function(){
            if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Can you confirm exactly where I should place this in my javascript code?

Comment: In the code from your question you could place it right above the line `jQuery(function($){`.

Comment: My new code: http://pastebin.com/BYvX7eZh However, it still outputs the placeholder text in my $all variable.

Comment: Found a potential solution: http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/experiments/forms/input-placeholder-text/#test-form Stay tuned :-)

Comment: Yes. The above worked. I will post my adjustments shortly. Thanks everyone for your patience here :D

Answer (score 0):

HTTP doesn't post disabled inputs. Try disabling the inputs on submit of the form, so that it won't get posted to server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any chance you could provide a code example (using my code) to illustrate your answer? I'm not totally sure where to begin with this. Thank you :)